# Node.js | fs.readFileSync cannot find file that has just been saved in a folder

Tags: node.js, async-await, fs

In the code below I'm looping through an array of image URLs and for each image URL I downlaod the image and save it in a folder:

```
function downloadImg (url, imagePath) {
  axios({ url, responseType: 'stream' }).then((response) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      response.data
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath))
        .on('finish', () => resolve())
        .on('error', e => reject(e));
    })
  })
}

for (const img of imgs) {
  let imgPath = `${__dirname}/temp/${img.id}.jpg`
  let downloadedImg = await downloadImg(img.media_url, imgPath)
  console.log(imgPath) // returns the correct path
  console.log(fs.existsSync(imgPath)) // returns false
  
  // throws fs.readFileSync Error: "no such file or directory, open {imgPath}"
  doSomethingWith(imgPath)
}
```

When I then click on my `/temp` folder, the image file is there and working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the axios request in the Promise instead of the other way around fixed it:

```
function downloadImg (url, imagePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({ url, responseType: 'stream' }).then((response) => {
      response.data
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath))
        .on('finish', () => resolve())
        .on('error', e => reject(e))
    })
  })
}
```